# How can I generate fake data that adheres to the PRIMARY KEY-FOREIGN KEY constraints of my schema?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, ubuntu

I have a schema for which I would like to generate fake data. I can generate fake data using Python for each of the tables separately, but I don't know how to make sure the fake data generation adheres to the constraints I have set between the tables.

I would like to generate 1 million rows for each of the tables. My system is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

I came across Red Gate's SQL generator, but it is only for SQL Server AND available only in Windows. SQL Server is currently not available for Ubuntu 18.04 either. I currently have PostgreSQL and MySQL in my system.

http://www.generatedata.com I can install locally (didn't try it yet) but I still can't figure out how to make sure the data generation adheres to PK-FK constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, chain [data-modifying CTEs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) in **PostgreSQL** for the purpose. Details very much depend on the undisclosed details of your setup and specific requirements. The meaning of "random" varies wildly.

Minimal demo:

```
CREATE TABLE fk_tbl(fk_id serial PRIMARY KEY, data int);
CREATE TABLE pk_tbl(pk_id serial PRIMARY KEY, fk_id int REFERENCES fk_tbl, data int);

WITH ins1 AS (
   INSERT INTO fk_tbl(data)
   SELECT trunc(random() * 10000)::int      -- or whatever
   FROM   generate_series(1, 10) g          -- or 1000000 instead of 10?
   RETURNING fk_id
   )
INSERT INTO pk_tbl(fk_id, data)
SELECT fk_id, trunc(random() * 55555)::int  -- or whatever
FROM   ins1
ORDER  BY random();                         -- optional
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bfb4cebb3fba6cdd3e32572188dc18e7)*

Related:

- [Insert data in 3 tables at a time using Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20561627/939860)
- [How can I generate a random bytea](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22512/how-can-i-generate-a-random-bytea/22571#22571)
- [Best way to select random rows PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8675160/939860)
- [Set random value from set](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55363/set-random-value-from-set/55401#55401)

Comment: Hi thank you for he answer. This is basically a personal project of mine for which I would like to generate fake data. I have come up with the schema. I was thinking of generating data according to the schema. But I am now reevaluating whether I should generate the data first, then split it into NFs etc into the schema.